# Logic statements with predicate's

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I have this question:

Given $k,t$ and a prime number bigger than 1 ($p \geq 2$) and $k,t$ are naturals. Which of these predicates is the right for "p is a prime number":

1. $\forall k \forall t((p=kt) \wedge ((k=1) \vee (t=1)))$
2. $\forall k \forall t((k=1) \vee (t=1) \vee (p \neq kt))$
3. $\forall k \forall t(((k \neq 1) \vee (t \neq 1)) \rightarrow (p \neq kt))$
4. $\forall k \forall t(((k = 1) \vee (t=1)) \rightarrow (p \neq kt))$

I can find any $k,t$ that would contradict every option - so is there even a solution?  For example for 2:

I can find $k=1$ and $t=13$ and $p = 13$ which is a prime but it says $p \neq 13$ ... what?! how..

I would appreciate your help! Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 is correct. Either one of $k$ and $t$ is $1$ or $p$ isn't prime.

Note that none of the predicates directly defines *primes*.

The questions asks which predicate is correct *knowing* $p$ is prime.

- if $k=1$ then (2) is correct regardless of everything else
- if $t=1$ then (2) is correct regardless of everything else
- if $p\ne kt$ then (2) is correct regardless of everything else

If none of $k$ and $t$ are $1$ then the last one is correct. Otherwise one of the first two ones is correct.

Comment: But how? if there's an "or" connector - it means I can take "t=1" "k=13" and "p=17" still, p is a prime and the predicate is correct... because it's true that t=1 or k=1 or p $\neq$ 13 (because t=1 is true and the other ones are false)

Comment: Exactly. The connectors are disjunctions (ORs). Once one of them is correct the rest doesn't matter.

Comment: It seems odd because I can't make the actual statement that $p = kt$ for some integers $k,t$ if we must say that $p$ is prime because no prime consists of multiplying 2 natural numbers (greater than 2) so the only option left is that one of them is 1 and the other one is a prime / not a prime but again, what about $t=1$ - the other does not matter then how it tells me that $p$ is a prime? it can sometimes be not prime and so the other answers (1,3,4) can sometimes give primes and sometimes not

Comment: I mean, the quantifiers are "for all" then - i can find an example which is not true .... $t=2, k =7, p = 15$ ofcourse $p \neq 2 \cdot 7 = 14 \neq 15$ so it is true, and thus "nothing else matter" and so the predicate is true - but $15$ is not a prime... and thus the quantifier "for all" falls apart..

Comment: I think the question might have been a bit misleading. $p$ being prime is a *premise* and we are not looking to deduce it from anything. So your example with $p=15$ isn't a valid example for this question.

Comment: But I think that saying "p is a prime" is a premise - is the whole idea of proving that no two naturals (not 1) can multiply and give a prime (because it contradicts the def. of prime numbers) and so we cannot say that we are 100% sure that $p \neq tk$ because it is a "premise", because it seems like it is the whole idea of the question - I mean, it is ($p \neq tk$) is even in some predicates here

Comment: I'm not sure these little boxes for chatting are the best place to communicate ideas easily. But I guess to summarize my point I'd say the question should be "For $k,t \in \mathbb{N}$ and for a prime $p > 1$ which one is correct?"